# Can you omit 'it is' from "it is likely that blah blah"?

Tags: word-usage

> To every ones amazement, the ring world has erupted into a flurry of color as thousands of space worms, or as it seems, larvae, are transforming into butterflies. **Likely** the change has been brought on by the generation of an atmosphere

Is 'Likely' here, actually, "It is likely the change has..."? '

Comment: Yes, you could read that as "It is likely the change ..."

Comment: It depends how grammatically correct you wish to be. "Likely" is an adjective, not an adverb. It means "probable". So "it is likely" is perfect grammar but "likely the change" means "**probable** the change": not "**probably** the change", which is what you mean. "A likely outcome" is correct because an adjective is needed. "Likely he was drunk" is wrong because it means "probable he was drunk." However, the adverbial use of 'likely' is a feature of some dialects - famously Yorkshire - and nowadays it may be gaining more widespread acceptance.